# How can i find where two functions meet to have the same gradient?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, graphing-functions

I have two functions, ax^2 and clog(x)-2. How can I find the point where they can meet at a gradient that is the same.

Comment: Hi Luke. You should consider formatting your question so the mathematical expressions are more understandable; here's a tutorial on how to do it: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: ive decided i got the answer anyway. i got c=ax^2 by setting their differentials equal to one another and i belive this is as far as it will go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're asking when the two functions $ax^2$ and $c \text{log}(x) - 2 $ have the same gradient for any given real number $a$ and $c$, you can start of by finding the derivative of both functions, i.e.

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[ax^2\right] = 2ax
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[c \ \text{log}(x) - 2 \right] = \frac{c}{x}
$$

Then to find the point where they are equal, you can equate them:

$$
2ax = \frac{c}{x}
$$

And now you can solve for $x$ (Note: you may need to assert conditions on $a$ and $c$ if you'll be taking square roots!).

Comment: okay cool this is what i had oopsie, thanks.